# Snapshot extension registration failed Geth- Go Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I was trying to Mine some Görli Testnet. It's been almost a week and i can't mine and sync the node.
First I was syncing the node on CPU with CPU mining. The node synced completely after 3 days and eth.syncing was returning false. That means that my node is not syncing more or completely synced but then I realized that node is taking too much storage(One issue). The command I was using is

**Geth --goerli --datadir "E:"**

After syncing of complete node I start mining using,

geth attach ipc://./pipe/geth.ipc
personal.newAccount()
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
miner.start(8)

and it returns that **Mining is aborted due to unsync**. and **eth.hashrate = 0** always.
Then i used ubuntu on Aws server to save my Time and storage. I started to sync the node but getting error, showing me always "connecting to Peers" and this error,

**Snapshot extension registration failed peer=0a807721 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support".**

I am using this command:
**geth --goerli --datadir Ethereum/ --port=30303 --syncmode full --http --http.addr 'localhost' --http.port 8501 --http.api 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --networkid 5 --miner.gasprice '0' -unlock '0x98d692FB78583c4936B8CE7eF4F332191195B5FA' --password Ethereum/password.txt --mine --allow-insecure-unlock**

Geth
Version: 1.10.21-stable
Git Commit: 671094279e8d27f4b4c3c94bf8b636c26b473976
Git Commit Date: 20220727
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.18.4
Operating System: windows
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
Ubuntu on Aws server

Note: After starting the node on server i also tried to sync the node on my CPU. It is showing me the same error on my CPU and also on server.

A little help would be appreciated. Thank you!
[image]